# VB.NET:Updating record in Ms Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, insert-update

I am creating an employee timing sheet in which they have to insert their timings through pressing timein and timeout buttons. For timein I am creating a new record in database, for that person, and for timeout I am using UPDATING command to update that existing record. Here is my code:

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(ssda)
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["
    cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "UPDATE emp_timing SET emp_timing.emp_timeout = '" & OnlyTime & "' WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)='" & TextBox1.Text & "') AND ((emp_timing.day)=" & Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "))"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)


    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Data added")

        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

My code is working fine but the problem is that it is not updating records in database.

Datatype for fields in Access:
emp_code = Number, emp_timeout = Text, day = Date/Time.

Comment: This happens because you don't use parameters but you concatenate strings leaving the conversion to whatever your locale is.

Comment: How should I resolve this ? @Steve

Comment: Are your fields emp_timeout and  day of type datetime?

Comment: emp-timeout is of Text and day is of datetime

Comment: Will only update where the emp_code precisely matches the text entered in TextBox1 (you shouldn't pass this value directly into the database, you should probably validate it first and ensure no SQL Injection can take place. Also, your emp_timing.day is matching on a string, but it is not enclosed in single quotes. It looks like a date, but you're not doing any explicit conversion here. So, I would suspect that this would update 0 records, based on the code so far.

Comment: It is ***extremely*** difficult to search related questions here which do not explain, demonstrate, illustrate and advise SQL Parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual this is caused by your code not using the Parameters collection to pass values to the database engine. This is not really understood until you hit a conversion problem as always happens with dates

```
str = "UPDATE emp_timing SET emp_timeout = @p1 " & _
      "WHERE emp_code = @p2 AND day = @p3"


Using con = new OleDbConnection( dbProvider & dbSource)
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, con)

    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = OnlyTime
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day)
    Try
        Dim rowsAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        if rowsAdded > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Data added")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox1.Focus()
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: When I am pressing the button its not responding.